# Save method is not triggering on object save

Tags: python, django, save

I have a save method on my model which I would like to use to validate the fields (I did this in my views before but it was just messy!). I'm saving an object rather than a form because I was having some difficulties with the form validation.

I haven't used save methods before, but I assume they trigger when you use the .save() command? Mine isn't triggering at all... Also from what I understand a clean() method is run for forms when you use is_valid(), so isn't useful for me here?

Here is my view that saves an object using ajax

```
@login_required
def createtimesheet(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print "creating timesheet"
        # Get the person from the previous view
        person_object = request.session.get('person')
        person = Person.objects.get(id=person_object)
        # get the POST data
        start_date = request.POST.get('datestart')
        end_date = request.POST.get('dateend')
        start_date_formatted = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
        end_date_formatted = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
        start_date_print = start_date_formatted.strftime("%B")[0:3] + ". " + start_date_formatted.strftime("%d") + ", " + start_date_formatted.strftime("%Y")
        end_date_print = end_date_formatted.strftime("%B")[0:3] + ". " + end_date_formatted.strftime("%d") + ", " +  end_date_formatted.strftime("%Y")

        response_data = {}

        # create our messages
        message = ""
        error = ""

        todays_date = datetime.now()
        print_date = todays_date.strftime("%A")      

        # now we can create the timesheet!
        peach = TimeSheet(start_date=start_date_formatted, end_date=end_date_formatted, person_id=person)
        # need an if valid.....? 
        peach.save()
        message = "Created new timesheet"

        response_data['startdate'] = start_date_print
        response_data['enddate'] = end_date_print
        response_data['status'] = peach.status
        print response_data

        context = {
            "person": person,
            "message": message,
            "error": error,
            "print_date": print_date,
            "todays_date": todays_date,
        }

        return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

And here is where I have attempted to write a save method... I'm planning to have a much longer validation function to check if the dates fall on certain days, but for now I just want to get this to work.

```
class TimeSheet(models.Model):

    O = "Open"
    S = "Submitted"
    A = "Approved"
    R = "Needs review"

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (O, "Open"),
    (S, "Submitted"),
    (A, "Approved"),
    (R, "Needs Reviewing"),
    )

    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    person_id = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    status = models.CharField(max_length= 50, default="Open", choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    submitted_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    approved_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    submitted_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    approved_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    # def __str__(self):
    #   return self.id

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tande:timesheet', kwargs={'id': self.id})

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "initiating a timesheet"
        super(TimeSheet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "something is trying to save!"
        ok_to_continue = True
        start_date = self.start_date
        end_date = self.end_date
        if ok_to_continue:
            if end_date < start_date:
                error = "Start date must be before end date"
                ok_to_continue = False
        if ok_to_continue:
            super(TimeSheet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        else: 
            print "def save did not work"
```

Thanks!

Edit: here is the ajax call

```
$( document ).ready(function()  {

$('#timesheet-form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("add a timesheet");
    createtimesheet();
});

function createtimesheet() {
    console.log("create timesheet is working!")
    $.ajax({
        url : "{% url 'tande:createtimesheet' %}",
        type: "POST",
        data: { datestart : $('#start').val(), dateend : $('#end').val()},

        success : function(json) {
            $('#start').val('');
            $('#end').val('');

            console.log(json);
            var html = '<tr><td>'+json.startdate+'</td><td>'+json.enddate+'</td><td>'+json.status+'</td><</tr>';
            console.log("success"); 
            // $('div#talk').html(html);
            $('#timesheet-list').append(html);
            console.log(html)
            overlay();
        },

        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            // $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
            //     " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
            console.log("uh oh"); 
            }
        });
    };
})
```

URLs:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^people/$', views.people, name='people'),
    url(r'^people/create_person/$', views.create_person, name='create_person'),
    url(r'^(?P<person_id>[0-9]+)/person/$', views.person, name='person' ),
    url(r'^person/createtimesheet/$', views.createtimesheet, name='createtimesheet' ),

    url(r'^(?P<timesheet_id>[0-9]+)/person/timesheet/$', views.timesheet, name='timesheet' ),

]
```

Comment: Are you certain the view is actually called with POST? Do you see the `creating timesheet`?

Comment: No I don't see the creating timesheet. It was all working fine I get the data with Ajax and send it to this view to avoid a page refresh. Then call the view in Ajax. Since I added a save method it's stopped doing anything...

Comment: Can you show us the ajax call? It's most likely missing the POST method.

Comment: Just made an edit with it!

Comment: Thanks. I don't see anything wrong with it at a glance. Can you make sure your view is being hit (print something before the first `if`)?

Comment: It's not running the view at all. But it's running a different one (it's running the one associated with the template) so my submit button isn't triggering the view properly...

Comment: Can you give us your URL config?

Comment: Okay I'm an idiot - my form id didn't match the id in my ajax call. This is what happens when I code on Friday evenings -.-

Comment: Haha, ok. Pro-tip: matching for an integer is also `\d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

form id didn't match the id in the ajax call...

id in html is 'create-timesheet-form' and ajax was calling 'timesheet-form'

-.-